# Mount Azure Files' folder into Kubernetes?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-storage-files

As [direct mount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume) or [persistent volume claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv) the Azure docs show how to mount an Azure Files storage account to a Kubernetes pod.  This mounts the entire storage as the mounted path.  How do I instead mount a folder within the Azure Files storage to Kubernetes?

On Azure Files, I have the following:

```
AzureFiles
|- folder1
   |- file1
|- folder2
   |- file2
```

When I mount the Azure Files storage account to Kubernetes (to `/mnt/azure`) I see this:

```
/mnt
|- azure
   |- folder1
      |- file1
   |- folder2
      |- file2
```

Instead I'd like to see this when I mount Azure Files' path `folder1`:

```
/mnt
|- azure
   |- file1
```

How do I change my [Pod definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume#mount-the-file-share-as-a-volume) to specify this path:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - // ... snip ...
    volumeMounts:
      - name: azure
        mountPath: /mnt/azure
  volumes:
  - name: azure
    azureFile:
      secretName: azure-secret
      shareName: aksshare
      readOnly: false
      // TODO: how to specify path in aksshare
```

Comment: Any more question? Or if the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Comment: @CharlesXu: the hard part of accepting is both answers work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**

Search for several days, I figure out how to mount a sub-folder of the Azure File Share to the AKS pod. You can set the yaml file like this:

```
volumes:
  - name: azure
    azureFile:
      secretName: azure-secret
      shareName: share/subfolder
      readOnly: false
```

Just set the share name with the directory, take care, do not append `/` in the end. The screenshot of the result is here:

[image]

For more details, see [Naming and Referencing Shares, Directories, Files, and Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-shares--directories--files--and-metadata#directory-and-file-names%3Chttps://emea01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Frest%2Fapi%2Fstorageservices%2Fnaming-and-referencing-shares--directories--files--and-metadata%23directory-and-file-names&data=02%7C01%7C%7C851c8a59e3b64c291a5508d65ea91a95%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636800477728798195&sdata=v3XdE1qMeZFVcD1qYCoeGyDjmXo4GvwsChdMIws8XA4%3D&reserved=0%3E).

Comment: For me, the share/subfolder needed a backslash (I worked with windows containers): `share\subfolder`. Error msg with slash:
`MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "myvolume" : New-SmbGlobalMapping failed: exit status 1, output: "New-SmbGlobalMapping : Generic failure \r\nAt line:1 char:190\r\n+ ... ser, $PWord;New-SmbGlobalMapping -RemotePath $Env:smbremotepath -Cred ...\r\n+\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_SmbGlobalMapping:ROOT/Microsoft/...mbGlobalMapping) [New-SmbGlobalMa \r\n   pping], CimException\r\n + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041001,New-SmbGlobalMapping`

Comment: @hey You need to add another question in SO and provide more details so that the communities can provide more exact help.

Comment: It's a solution already; sorry for not being clear enough: The answer worked for me in principle, but due to the fact that I run windows nodes, I had to use a backslash.

Comment: @hey I think you must forget to difference between Linux and Windows path :-)

Comment: yes, @charles-xu, Some softwares translate paths correctly, some translate them in a custom way, others don't translate at all. Can be confusing. ;)

Comment: @hey It also shows [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-node-limitations#is-kubernetes-different-on-windows-and-linux).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use [`subPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath). So something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - // ... snip ...
    volumeMounts:
      - name: azure
        mountPath: /mnt/azure
        subPath: folder1
  volumes:
  - name: azure
    azureFile:
      secretName: azure-secret
      shareName: aksshare
      readOnly: false
      // TODO: how to specify path in aksshare
```

Comment: I work with windows containers. For me, using "subPath" resulted in the same problem as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860721/failed-to-prepare-subpath-for-volumemount ( `Error: failed to create subPath directory for volumeMount "myvolume" of container "mypod"` )