# Failed to prepare subPath for volumeMount

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

Getting this error.

`Error: failed to prepare subPath for volumeMount "solr-collection-config" of container "upload-config-container"`

Using kubernetes **1.10.11**

```
      - name: upload-config-container
        image: solr:7.4.0-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "100m"
          limits:
            memory: "256Mi"
            cpu: "200m"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: solr-collection-config
          mountPath: /tell/carbon/conf
          subPath: conf
```

`solr-collection-config` is a volume that represents a ConfigMap

```
     volumes:
      - name: solr-collection-config
        configMap:
          name: solr-collection-resources
          items:
          - key: stopwords_en.txt
            path: "conf/lang/stopwords_en.txt"
          - key: _rest_managed.json
            path: "conf/_rest_managed.json"
          - key: currency.xml
            path: "conf/currency.xml"
          - key: protwords.txt
            path: "conf/protwords.txt"
          - key: schema.xml
            path: "conf/schema.xml"
          - key: solrconfig.xml
            path: "conf/solrconfig.xml"
          - key: stopwords.txt
            path: "conf/stopwords.txt"
          - key: synonyms.txt
            path: "conf/synonyms.txt"
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Help is kindly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens if you do not use `subPath`?

All keys from **configMap** will be mounted in directory `/tell/carbon/conf`. That means, every key will be a separate file under this directory.

Now, what this `subPath` does? From your example,

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: solr-collection-config
    mountPath: /tell/carbon/conf
    subPath: conf
```

Means, key `conf` from **configMap** will be mounted as file `conf` under `/tell/carbon` directory.

But, you do not have this key. So getting this error.

> Error: failed to prepare subPath for volumeMount "solr-collection-config" of container "upload-config-container"

Now, you can do like this

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: solr-collection-config
    mountPath: /tell/carbon/conf
    subPath: stopwords_en.txt
```

Which means, value of `stopwords_en.txt` from your **configMap** will be mounted as `conf` file under `/tell/carbon`.

Final words, this `subPath` is actually a path from volume, from where your data is coming. In your case, `subPath` should be one of the key from your **configMap**

Comment: Question. The  yaml I pasted was working for kubernetes 1.9.3  but stopped when i upgraded to kube 1.10.11 - was the spec later changed because of a security bug in subpath

Comment: Not sure about the change. If I find out, will let you know