# Kubernetes - can we use the same mounted volume (file share) for both Cluster Nodes - Windows and Linux?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I initially had only app on Linux node and used mounted volume for it (Azure Storage Account and File Share), and everything works perfectly.

Extracted definition from YAML:

```
    volumeMounts:
      - name: test-volume
        mountPath: /opt/arena/
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    azureFile:
      secretName: test-secret
      shareName: test-share
```

Now for my second app (same app but deployed on Windows container) I need to use the same storage account and file share.
Only I will mount windows path.

```
....
    volumeMounts:
      - name: test-volume
        mountPath: "C:\\arena"
    ........ 
  volumes:
    - name: test-volume
      azureFile:
        secretName: test-secret
        shareName: test-share
```

When mounted for linux I am getting immediately my log directory with file "ads.log"

```
log
|__ads.log
```

But the same directory "log" and the same file "ads.log" exists on the Windows container as well.

I would like to use the same storage account and file share on Azure in order not to increase costs.
But how I can achieve that both Linux and Windows containers are mounted into volumes but also in the same time to differentiate which log is from which container???

Also additional question since I didn't yet do the windows mounting: is the `mountPath: "C:\\arena"` correct way of defining this? Because in some examples on web some plugins are mentioned for windows etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the mount format for windows is right. So you don't need to worry about it. Second, to differentiate the log folder which is for Linux container and which is for windows container from the same file share, you can mount the subfolders of the file share.

File Share:

```
aksshare
│── linux
│── windows
```

screenshot:

[image]

Then the mount the file share like this:

```
  .....
  volumeMounts:
    - name: azure
      mountPath: /mnt/azure
volumes:
  - name: azure
    azureFile:
      shareName: aksshare/linux
      secretName: azure-secret
```

This way will mount the two subfolders of the file share to the different containers and won't affect each other.

Comment: sorry Charles but this does not work. 
If I add slash to your definition then I get this error:
`Warning  FailedMount   kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "ads-win-filesharevolume" : exit status 1
  Warning  FailedMount  2m6s (x2 over 4m22s)  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[ads-win-filesharevolume],
  unattached volumes=[ads-win-filesharevolume default-token-nx49r]: timed out waiting for the condition`

If I remove slash `aksshare/windows` to `aksshare` then I get up and running but they are not separated

Comment: please take a look at the bottom comment on this answer, I think you were involved also for this answer. Comment from the response is that we should use backslash and not slash, correct? - it does not work slash on Windows  :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599796/mount-azure-files-folder-into-kubernetes

Comment: @AndreyDonald I also mount for windows container and it works fine. But maybe you need to change the volume into `aksshare\windows`. It seems the difference between windows and linux.

Comment: ok Charles thanks. Can you please assist me with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709259/kubernetes-cannot-have-windows-path-mounted-on-azure-file-share-linux-mountin please let me know if I need to provide some logs or configuration

Comment: @AndreyDonald Well, I will take a look. If I have any solution, I will provide it.